# Groovy/Grails default error message

Tags: grails, internationalization

I'm trying to customize my errors mesages. Firstly, I want to get message key on output as an error, for example: package.Subpage.title.nullable.

To gain this goal I've deleted all message.properties bundles from my application but I still get something like this on output:

```
   Property [title] of class [class package.Subpage] cannot be blank
```

I've got properties of FieldError class to see if it's implemented there and I've noticed that this class has property:

```
   defaultMessage=Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be blank
```

Of course I know that there is a pattern for message key which looks like class.property.(blank or nullable or whatever constraint set) and I can override every message, but my main goal is to have full control on this how message key, message value and default message look like.

**Question:** Is there any way to define default message and message key for errors in grails?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own Spring `MessageSource`, then wire that into Grails:

- [MessageSource JavaDoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html)
- [Spring Refence - Internationalization using MessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource)
- [Using the Spring Bean DSL in Grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html#14.2%20Configuring%20Additional%20Beans)